# Selenium IDE: Automate the task

Tags: selenium-ide

I want to automate the task of checking link by datewise, download the file and verify the excel sheet contents.
Steps:
1. Open URL. It will display the links of file(xxxx_130112_130208_xxx.xlsx). 
2. click and download matched date link. It will download excel sheet.
3. Search the content and display report.

Please let me know if any idea regarding this. Can we automate this scenario.

-sri

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do anything outside the browser. The only thing allowed is to use ClickOkOnNextConfirmation to click OK in dialog. But it will not work for saving the file. That's how Selenium IDE works.